# How to pass the credentials to consume an asmx service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asp.net-web-api, asmx

I am trying to consume a SAP web service  in console application which requires authentication. I added the service reference  to the console application.

```
        ServiceReference1.SAPServiceSoapClient myService = new ServiceReference1.SAPServiceSoapClient();

        System.Net.CredentialCache myCredentials = new System.Net.CredentialCache();

        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");

        Uri uriPrefix = new Uri("url");

        myCredentials.Add(uriPrefix, "Basic", netCred);

       //The following line is giving error that ClientCredentials cannot be assigned as it is read only.            

        myService.ClientCredentials = myCredentials;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following code:

```
AuthenticationToken token=new AuthenticationToken();
token.UserName="username";
token.Password="password";
```